# Can I use a for loop inside the string.format method?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a list to a file. When I use the following code it gives me an error :

```
    with open('list.txt', 'w') as fref :
        fref.writelines('{}\n'.format(item for item in item_list))
```

But when I modify the code to :

```
    with open('list.txt', 'w') as fref :
        for item in item_list :
            fref.writelines('{}\n'.format(item))
```

or

when I format the string using % :

```
    with open('list.txt', 'w') as fref :
        fref.writelines('%s\n' % item for item in item_list)
```

it works fine. I am confused as to why does the for loop inside the format method fail ?

Comment: `{}` is a position based format. You cant provide multiple strings for one position. If you check the 3rd one. It's same as the 2nd one, you are just passing multiple lines to `writelines` function.

Comment: The equivalent format expression for the latter two is `'{}\n'.format(item) for item in item_list`.  Note the format being applied inside the generator expression, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
    with open('list.txt', 'w') as fref :
        fref.writelines('%s\n' % item for item in item_list)
```

Can be read as (note the parenthesis):

```py
    with open('list.txt', 'w') as fref :
        fref.writelines(('%s\n' % item) for item in item_list)
```

You pass `file.writelines` a generator expression, in which each item is a formatted string.

While:

```py
    with open('list.txt', 'w') as fref :
        fref.writelines('{}\n'.format(item for item in item_list))
```

Creates a generator expression of arguments, that will be sent 1 time to the `str.format` method.

Instead, create a generator expression which calls `str.format` for each item in `item_list`:

```py
    with open('list.txt', 'w') as fref :
        fref.writelines('{}\n'.format(item) for item in item_list)
```

Now `file.writelines` receives generator expression of strings as an argument.